# Setup doesn't seem to register and MockException is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, installation, moq

I have these mocks:

```
_processWrapperMock = new Mock<IProcessWrapper>(MockBehavior.Strict);
_processStartInfoMock = new Mock<IProcessStartInfo>();
```

and a setup for the `Start()` method:

```
_processWrapperMock.Setup(m => m.Start(_processStartInfoMock.Object))
                   .Returns(new Process());
```

and my `_processWrapperMock` instance is passed to the constructor for the object which contains the method I'm testing.

```
var wrapper = new WrapperClassImTesting(_processWrapperMock.Object);
```

I then execute the method which I'm testing:

```
byte[] output = wrapper.MethodImTesting(someParams);
```

Within `MethodImTesting`, the `Start` method of the `_processWrapperMock` is executed however my previous setup doesn't seem to be taken into account. The error I get is at the line:

```
using (var process = _processWrapper.Start(processStartInfo))
```

throwing:

> Mock Exception was unhandled by user code
>
> IProcessWrapper.Start(GraphVizWrapper.ProcessStartInfo) invocation
> failed with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on the mock must
> have a corresponding setup.

What am I doing / not doing, that I need to for this to work as I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother creating a mock at all ... can't you just do this?

```
_processWrapperMock.Setup(m => m.Start(It.IsAny<IProcessStartInfo>)).Returns(new Process());
```

Are you sure there isn't some other method or property that's being accessed?

Comment: If I don't pas in a mock to the Start method then I get an "StandardIn has not been redirected" exception. This doesn't answer my question though since you're still doing a setup for the Start method which is the one I'm having problems with.

Comment: There are other calls to other methods within my test method, and the mocks/setups for these are working fine. I only receive the error when _processWrapper.Start(param) is executed.

Comment: I thought maybe it wasn't recognising that setup because it is being done with a specific instance rather than It.IsAny so maybe a different instance was being passed in to what it was expecting. If the above didn't fix that then I guess that isn't the case.

Comment: You may be right but I need to pass an instance because certain properties need to be set. Is there a way I can do that without the instance?

Comment: Any properties you are setting up on the mock IProcessStartInfo instance would be ignored wouldn't they as you are just returning a new Process() when Start is called?

Comment: This answer was actually really helpful. As you alluded, the issue was actually with the parameter I was passing to the start method. I didn't realise it would be expecting the exact same object being passed in the live code and so there was a mismatch between the setup parameter and the live parameter. I'll accept this as accepted since you provided the most helpful answer.

Comment: Sweet :)... thanks for the accept and glad I could at least point in the direction of a solution

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this just mean that a method was called on your mock that you hadn't explicitly accounted for with a SetUp method?

I generally avoid strict mocks as they lead to brittle tests but if you do need them then I'd make sure nothing is getting called that you weren't expecting

Comment: The exception does seem to mean that yes but as you can see, I have explicitly accounted for the method call with a setup.

Comment: But are you sure it's complaining about the Start method? If another method is called (or Start is called more than once maybe) wouldn't you see the same error? What happens if you don't use 'Strict'?

Comment: Thanks @JRoughan. You're right, the problem was with the parameter I was passing. See my final comment on iDevForFun's answer for a fuller explination. Thanks again for you help. Between the other answer and your comment I managed to track down the issue.